# how do I use two methods to print out asterisks?

Tags: java, methods

My program asks for a number, converts it into a binary, adds zeros until it is 8 characters long, then I need it to print out in asterisks what the binary is, the space should be 5 across and five long IE:
a zero would be five asterisk first line; one asterisk, three spaces, and one asterisk for second, third, and fourth line; then another five asterisks for the fifth line. 
a one would be two spaces and an asterisks for all five lines.
I can't figure this one out for the life of me.I am not allowed to use arrays for this project.
This is for homework, I am not asking for someone to code for me, just some suggestions on how I could do it. I am out of ideas. Thank you in advance
Below is my code:

```
    public static void getChara(String o){
      char e=0;
      int g=0;
      int h=0;
      for (g=0;g<5;g++){
          for (h=0;h<8;h++){
            e = o.charAt(h);  
             if ((g == 1) || (g == 5)){
            if(h == 0)
                printDigit(g,h);
            else if(h==1)
                printDigit(g,h);}
        else {
            if(h == 0)    
                printDigit(g,h);
            else if(h==1)
                printDigit(g,h);   }
         }
      }
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    System.out.println();
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    System.out.println();
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    System.out.println();
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    System.out.println();
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h); printDigit(g,h);
    System.out.println();

    }

    public static void printDigit(int g, int h){

        if ((g == 1) || (g == 5)){
            if(h == 0)
                System.out.print("***** ");
            else if(h==1)
                System.out.print("  *   ");}
        else {
            if(h == 0)    
                System.out.print("*   * ");
            else if(h==1)
                System.out.print("  *   ");   } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking `getChara` a bit.  `printDigit` does all of the work of printing the star patterns, so you don't need to duplicate that logic in `getChara`.  All `getChara` needs to do is tell `printDigit` to output the correct lines of the correct digits in the proper order, something like this:

```
public static void getChara(String o){
    for (int row=0; row < 5; ++row){
        for (int i=0; i < o.length(); ++i){
            int digit = o.charAt(i) == '0' ? 0 : 1;
            printDigit(row, digit);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```